# Is there anyway to use blob_client.query_blob() asyncronously for the python azure blob storage SDK?

Tags: python, azure, asynchronous, azure-blob-storage

```
azure.storage.blob.aio import BlobServiceClient as BlobServiceClientAsync


async def query_blob_async(self): 
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClientAsync.from_connection_string(
            self.connection_string_srct.get_secret_value()
        )
        async with blob_service_client:
            container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(self.container)
            blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob)
            data_reader = await blob_client.query_blob(  # nosec
                f"SELECT * FROM BlobStorage where measurement_source_id in {in_string}",
                blob_format=parquet_format,
                output_format=csv_format,
            )
```

I am trying to use blob*client.query_*blob() asynchronously but when attempting with the code above I am getting the following error:

'cannot unpack non-iterable coroutine object'.

I can see that the blob_client object has the query_blob method but can't see any documentation anywhere on how to use it asynchronously. Any help would be massively appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the results:**

You can use the below code to **`query_blobs`** with azure-blob storage.

**Code:**

```
import asyncio
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, DelimitedJsonDialect, DelimitedTextDialect

async def query_blob_async():
    connection_string = "<connect-string>"
    container_name = "test3"
    blob_name = "Employee Sample Data.csv"
    
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)
    query_expression = "SELECT _2 from BlobStorage"
    input_format = DelimitedTextDialect(delimiter=',', quotechar='"', lineterminator='\n', escapechar="", has_header=False)
    output_format = DelimitedJsonDialect(delimiter='\n')

    reader = blob_client.query_blob(query_expression, blob_format=input_format, output_format=output_format)
    content = reader.readall()
    print(content)
    
asyncio.run(query_blob_async())
```

**Output:**

The above query was executed successfully and you can view the second column of the CSV file.

```
b'{"_1":"Full Name"}\n{"_1":"Kai Le"}\n{"_1":"Robert Patel"}\n{"_1":"Cameron Lo"}\n{"_1":"Harper Castillo"}\n{"_1":"Harper Dominguez"}\n{"_1":"Ezra Vu"}\n{"_1":"Jade Hu"}\n{"_1":"Miles Chang"}\n{"_1":"Gianna Holmes"}\n{"_1":"Jameson Thomas"}\n{"_1":"Jameson Pena"}\n{"_1":"Bella Wu"}\n{"_1":"Jose Wong"}\n{"_1":"Lucas Richardson"}\n{"_1":"Jacob Moore"}\n{"_1":"Luna Lu"}\n{"_1":"Bella Tran"}\n{"_1":"Ivy Chau"}\n{"_1":"Jordan Kumar"}\n{"_1":"Sophia Gutierrez"}\n{"_1":"Eli Dang"}\n{"_1":"Lillian Lewis"}\n{"_1":"Serenity Cao"}\n{"_1":"Parker Lai"}\n
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[azure.storage.blob.BlobClient class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-query-blob)